# Dragon summoning spell

Tags: wordplay, enigmatic-puzzle, graph-theory, topology

The parchment shown below got stained with something.  See if you can determine the obscured parts.

[image: Dragon summoning spell]

Comment: Out of curiosity, it the story part of the puzzle?

Comment: @PrinceDeepthinker — Suffice to say, there is a lot of extraneous information in this puzzle!  Solvers on this site seem to enjoy a narrative.  Do you think it would be a better puzzle if I removed the story?

Comment: No just state that it is pure flavour text.

Comment: I'd say no need to explain away flavour text. Just add the 'story' tag :)

Comment: +1 just for the flavor text and nice presentation. Got me lured here :c)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So one key rule we must satisfy is that

> Each two-letter pair must form a four-letter word when put together with any of the two-letter pairs it's connected to. For example, CE is connected to LI, MI, NT, LL and so can form the words LICE, MICE, CENT and CELL. Under these conditions I was able to find a few solutions, the most satisfying of which is probably the following
>  [image]
>  So we see that CA joins with VE, NE, ST and GE to form the words CAVE, CANE, CAST and CAGE and GE joins with CA, AR, NE and TS to form CAGE, GEAR, GENE and GETS.

However, this does not tie in with the title so I thought a better fit would be the following

> [image]
>  where FI combines with VE, NE, ST, RE to form FIVE, FINE, FIST, FIRE and RE combines with FI, AR, NE, TS to form the words FIRE, REAR, [NERE](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Nere) and [RETS](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/ret).
>  And one can imagine that a Dragon summoning spell would involve **FIRE** in some way.

Comment: Bravo for coming up with two solutions!  I hadn't even thought about constructing the puzzle out of dragon- related words.  I just had in mind an incantation of seemingly arbitrary words, like when Bart Simpson tries to call the zombies back to their graves.  But now that you mention it, I might go back and see if I can construct a solution made entirely out of dragon-related words...

Comment: Nice! I completely missed half the qualifications and just came up with Rot13 "OB NE".

Answer (score 2):

I think they must be

> **PA** and **GE**, which kinda matches what we see in the picture, and conceivably you could also do that to summon a dragon that has a pager :-)

These letter pairs

> form common words along the connecting lines:
>  **PAVE, PANE, PAST, PAGE, GEAR, GENE, GETS**

EDIT: looks like this answer has a lot in common with @hexomino's earlier answer. I guess it couldn't be helped though.

Comment: Bravo for coming up with another nice solution!  I hadn't even thought about constructing the puzzle out of dragon-related words.  I just had in mind an incantation of seemingly arbitrary words, like when Bart Simpson tries to call the zombies back to their graves.  But now that you mention it, I might go back and see if I can construct a solution made entirely out of dragon-related words...

Comment: One thing I've learned dabbling in the wordplay business is that it is almost impossible to construct a word puzzle which has exactly one and only one solution.  People are working from too many different word lists.  So I just have to aim for "tight enough" and see who comes up with a solution first.