# Alchemy in a Tin Kit

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual, chemistry

As usually happens when rummaging through one's grandparents' attic, I unwittingly discovered a seemingly ancient papyrus manuscript. It was stored in an old tin box along with some utensils. I carefully removed and unfolded the paper and this is what I saw:
[image: Old paper including elements on the periodic table, with shapes above them.]
What could it be?

Comment: Bravo!  I'm glad to see I wasn't the only one who thought that Matura MT was the right script for parchment:
https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/105275/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is

> a "cookbook" of sorts! If you replace each element with its symbol (and the two backwards elements with their symbols backwards), you can anagram each group to get an Italian food:
>
>  `Bi S Te C Ca`
>  `F Ag I O Li`
>  `La S Ag Na`
>  `mA C Ar O Ni`
>  `Ra V I O Li`
>  `S P Ag H eT Ti`
>
>  The black shapes above each group are the silhouettes of the food being made.

Comment: Nice! And just for completion, what is the significance of the black shapes? And the title?

Comment: @cap Ah, added the shapes. Not sure about the title, though...

Comment: rot13(V guvax gur gvgyr vf fbzr nantenz, cbffvoyl ZL VGNYVNA XVGPURA)

Answer (score 7):

In addition to Deusovi's answer,

> The title is an anagram of '**MY ITALIAN KITCHEN**'